# ElasticHQ: Unable to Connect to Server! Received Status Code: 0

Tags: elasticsearch

i am getting below error when i was trying to connect to Elastic HQ. Local instance of elasticsearch is running. Elastic search version is 2.0.0.

in the elasticsearch.yml,
http.cors.enabled: true  is set

Received the following error:

ElasticHQ: Unable to Connect to Server! Received Status Code: 0. A status code of 0, could mean the host is unreacheable or nothing is listening on the given port. Did you enable CORS?

am i missing something?

#### Elasticsearch Configuration

```
    # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
    #
    # Set the bind adress to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
    #
    network.host: 127.0.0.1
    #
    # Set a custom port for HTTP:
    #
    http.port: 9200
    
    http.cors.enabled: true
```

#### Browser Console Message

```
The browser console says 

Inside ErrorMessage
all.min.js:12 http://127.0.0.1:9200
all.min.js:12 Inside ClusterHealth
all.min.js:12 Inside ClusterState
all.min.js:12 Inside IndexStatsModel
all.min.js:12 Inside NodeList
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:9200/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
all.min.js:12 Failed to Connect on Ping!
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It works now!. i have to add another entry in elasticsearch.yml

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true 
node.master: true
```

Comment: As requested by my Collegue @Sumit,The complete set of configuration is here. So you dont have to read the entire thread

`http.cors.enabled: true`
`http.cors.allow-origin: "*"`
`node.master: true`

Answer (score 0):

you seems to say that you are able to connect to ES on local, but not from remote.
If that is the case, in your elasticsearch.yml file, bind the host to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for remote connections.

Include your yml file, if this is not the case.

Comment: Nope. This didn't work. Attached the elasticsearch.yml

Answer (score 0):

Check the developer console in your browser and see the response being sent back from the server (Elasticsearch).

Comment: Hi Roy Russo, thanks for your response. Attaching the brower console message in the question.

i made a fresh build of Elastic-HQ using npm install && grunt dist

Comment: It works now!. i have to add another entry in elasticsearch.yml 
"http.cors.allow-origin: "*"". i suggest this can be added to the elastic-hq github wiki page. i am sure may will face this issue.

Comment: It should rather be added to the error message when it can't connect. This is a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

- I was also getting same error while I was trying to run elasticHQ in
  ubuntu. Error message was:- **Unable to Connect to Server! Received
  Status Code: 0. A status code of 0, could mean the host is
  unreachable or nothing is listening on the given port.**

  To fix this issue I just added Few lines in **elasticsearch.yml** .
  File locate into **/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml** .

  At the bottom of elasticsearch.yml file add **http.cors.enabled:
  true** and restart elasticsearch with this command **sudo service
  elasticsearch restart**. Wait for at-least 10 seconds and then hit
  your elasticsearch HQ **index.html** url and once again register your
  running elasticsearch **http://domain:port** .

  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

set following lines in the config file

```
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length
```